# C# console program wait forever for event

Tags: c#

I have a simple C# console application that attaches to an event. I need the program to keep running continuously so it can respond to the event. What is the right way to keep it running?

Here is my application:

```
using System;
using NAudio.CoreAudioApi;

namespace MaxVolume
{
    class Program
    {
        private const float DesiredLevel = -15;
        private static MMDevice _device;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MMDeviceEnumerator mmde = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
            _device = mmde.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(DataFlow.Render, Role.Multimedia);

            _device.AudioEndpointVolume.MasterVolumeLevel = DesiredLevel;

            _device.AudioEndpointVolume.OnVolumeNotification += SetVolume;
        }

        static void SetVolume(AudioVolumeNotificationData data)
        {
            if (Math.Abs(data.MasterVolume - DesiredLevel) > 0.1)
            {
                _device.AudioEndpointVolume.MasterVolumeLevel = DesiredLevel;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should look into creating a windows service

Comment: @RobinNadeau ultimately i will, but for right now i need it to be a console app so that non-admin users can use it for testing.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can call `Console.ReadLine()` (if you want to terminate on keystroke), or simply `Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite)`.

Comment: Ding, we have a winner!

Answer (score 6):

In case of `async` main method, one could also use `await Task.Delay(-1);`

Answer (score -3):

You can just create a while-loop like so:

```
while(!eventFired) {}
```

and then have a field:

```
private bool eventFired = false;
```

and then finally when the event is fired make:

```
eventFired = true;
```

(if you want it to exit after the event was fired once, that is. if it should run forever see the other answers with sleep and readkey)

**NOTE**: this is using up a CPU and shouldn't be used in any production, but in a quick-and-dirty test setting it might be worth it.

Comment: This is not thread-safe, and will hang a CPU core.  Don't do that.

Comment: Edited it to reflect my thoughts on the use of it.