# Console Speech Recognition exits right after start

Tags: c#, mono, .net-core, voice-recognition

I tried to follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AB9lfHDOe5U) tutorial in building voice recognition C# app, the only difference is I wanted to have a `Console` app, not a Win Form app, so I wrote this this code:

```
using System;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
//using System.Speech.Synthesis;

namespace Voice_Recognation
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SpeechRecognitionEngine recEngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
            recEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();  

            Choices commands = new Choices();
            commands.Add(new string[] { "say Hi", "say Hello"});
            GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder();
            gb.Append(commands);
            Grammar g = new Grammar(gb);

            recEngine.LoadGrammarAsync(g);
            recEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);

            recEngine.SpeechRecognized += recEngine_SpeechRecognized;

        }

                // Create a simple handler for the SpeechRecognized event
        static void recEngine_SpeechRecognized (object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Speech recognized: {0}", e.Result.Text);
            switch(e.Result.Text){
                case "Red":
                    Console.WriteLine("you said hi"); 
                break;
                default:
                break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

and compiled it using mono project as below:

```
c:\mcs /reference:System.Speech.dll Program.cs
```

after adding the `System.Speech.dll` to the folder project, and got the `Program.exe` file generated.

Once I run the `program` at the terminal, it ends up directly, without giving me any chance to say anything!!

I've 2 questions:

What I'm missing here, and what the wrong thing I did?

and

How Is there a way to add the '.dll' file in a better way, I tried adding it to the `Project.json` file as below, but did not work, though I did not get any error at running `dotnet restore`:

```
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
                  "bin": {
            "assembly": "D:/2016/Speech/CORE/System.Speech.dll"
        },
     }
   }
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# console program wait forever for event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31323863/c-sharp-console-program-wait-forever-for-event)

Comment: Since you are using async methods you need to wait for some event to prevent exit from main. You can use Console.ReadLine for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the first part by adding `Thread.Sleep` so it give enough time for the thread to keep listening, another option is to make it endless loop using `while(true);`

I still could'not solve the second part which is how to make the VS code recognize the existing of the assembly file.

The new full code, if any is interested is below, and a more comprehensive code can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms554584(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
using System;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Threading;
//using System.Speech.Synthesis;

namespace Voice_Recognation
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SpeechRecognitionEngine recEngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
            recEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();  

            Choices commands = new Choices();
            commands.Add(new string[] { "say Hi", "say Hello"});
            GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder();
            gb.Append(commands);
            Grammar g = new Grammar(gb);

            recEngine.LoadGrammarAsync(g);


            recEngine.SpeechRecognized += recEngine_SpeechRecognized;
            Console.WriteLine("Starting asynchronous recognition...");
            recEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);

            // Wait 30 seconds, and then cancel asynchronous recognition.
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

            // or 
            // while(true);
        }

        // Create a simple handler for the SpeechRecognized event
        static void recEngine_SpeechRecognized (object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Speech recognized: {0}", e.Result.Text);
            switch(e.Result.Text){
                case "say Hello":
                    Console.WriteLine("you said hi"); 
                break;
                default:
                break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```